# How to make rows on bootstrap with unknown number of columns?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have dynamic generated columns that have variable width according to the user screen size:

[image: variable width]

How can I split these divs in rows?

Comment: Why do want to split them into rows? They can be in one `.row`.

Comment: @ZimSystem These divs are small call-to-actions to view videos. They contain a button that, when clicked, loads an AJAX page with more info about the video, such as description and a play button. This info should appear below the row. But currently I can only append it to the parent container, wich shows the "more info" on the footer of the page, or to the "div" itself, but it breaks the layout for the divs on the right of that row. It should append after the row, but there is no row. jQuery can't detect where a row ends or starts to append the "more info" block.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to split them into rows. Many responsive layouts require column units to **exceed 12 in a row**. This is known as column wrapping in Bootstrap.

If the content of the columns varies in height, you will need to use responsive resets to prevent the height problem. This will force a "wrap" every X number of columns, based on the tier.

[Clearfix Demo (responsive tiers)](http://bootply.com/89910)

There is also a [CSS-only variation](http://www.codeply.com/go/lUbs1JgXUd) of the 'clearfix'.

Comment: Great explanation of the height problem in the documentation link.  I have this exact problem in another project I put on the shelf to get around to fixing and stumbled across this.  Clearfix to the rescue!

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap row has a length of twelve, this means everything above twelve will be placed under the row. Unfortunately this is not looking nice. I do not know how you make the those divs. Assuming you pass an array to your front-end you can use javascript based on how many divs.

there is probaly a better way. I am new to programming, but would think of something like this:

Note that you need to change yourArray to the variable name of your array.

```
<div id="allRows">
<script>
    var mqxs = window.matchMedia( "(max-width: 767px)" );
    var mqsm = window.matchMedia( "(min-width: 768px)" );
    var mqmd = window.matchMedia( "(min-width: 992px)" );
    var mqlg = window.matchMedia( "(min-width: 1200px)" );
    var html = '<div class="row">';
    if (mqxs.matches){
        var max = 2;
        var count = 1;
        for(var i=0; i < yourArray.length; i++){
             if (var > max){
                 html += "</div>";
                 html+= "<div class='row'>";
                 count = 1;
             }
             html+= "<div class= 'col-xs-6>yourArray[i]'</div>";
             count += 1;
        }
    }else if (mqsm.matches){
        var max = 3;
        var count = 1;
        for(var i=0; i < yourArray.length; i++){
             if (var > max){
                 html += "</div>";
                 html+= "<div class='row'>";
                 count = 1;
             }
             html+= "<div class= 'col-sm-4'>yourArray[i]'</div>";
             count += 1;
        }
    }}else if (mqmd.matches){
        var max = 4;
        var count = 1;
        for(var i=0; i < yourArray.length; i++){
             if (var > max){
                 html += "</div>";
                 html+= "<div class='row'>";
                 count = 1;
             }
             html+= "<div class='col-md-3'>yourArray[i]'</div>";
             count += 1;
        }
    }else (mqlg.matches){
        var max = 6;
        var count = 1;
        for(var i=0; i < yourArray.length; i++){
             if (var > max){
                 html += "</div>";
                 html+= "<div class='row'>";
                 count = 1;
             }
             html+= "<div class= 'col-lg-2>yourArray[i]'</div>";
             count += 1;
        }
    }

    html += </div>
    document.getElementById("allRows").innerHTML = html;
</script>
</div>
```